# Asking female employees to come to my room

Tags: american-english, politeness, business-language, imperatives, gender-politics

I have a few female employees working at my office, and being a manager, I need to text them via [Skype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skype) or Messenger to come to my room.

How can I ask them politely to come?

> Please come to my room
>
> Please come here

I don't find either of these formulations helpful; what is appropriate?

Comment: Instead of "room" why not use "office"?  Since you are concerned regarding the gender (I assume you are male), add a summary of intent: "Please come to my office so that we can discuss XYZ."

Comment: @JeremyMiller correct, that is fine as well but kinda long as I dont have to give reason each and every time to discuss ABC and discuss XYZ, Please come to my office sounds like you are saying this to some outsider, since she is already in the office :)

Comment: Well, if you're *not* in the middle of a conversation, then context matters and is worth your time.  If, however, you are in a conversation, then simply saying, "let's chat about this in my office" will get to the point and be more conversational per Skype'ing etiquette (as informal as that is!)

Comment: Oh, and with the topic known, she can bring any supporting documentation or transfer files to you before going to your office to ensure efficiency.  Gender here doesn't matter as does clear intent and business efficiency.

Comment: Just re-read your comment about office.  Not true.  I use that all of the time at my office, asking people, "Can you come to my office?"  "Office" referencing the entire building and "office" representing my room within the office have never caused confusion.

Comment: At work, you have an "office", not a "room". (Yes, "the office" can mean the entire workplace, but that's a form of metonymy, where a part stands for the whole.) "Room" by itself very strongly implies *bedroom*, and in most cases is not the appropriate word to use for a workplace.

Comment: @Marthaª agreed not the right to use.. but office itself represents the building

Comment: @JeremyMiller yes but normally its not in the middle of conversation.

Comment: That's where you're not getting the full meaning.  If I say, "Let's meet at the office," then, yes, it means the whole building.  If I ask someone to come to my office, it is different.  "the office" is implied to mean "the business' building" whereas "my office" is my segment of that building.

Comment: English can be confusing this way -- a word having multiple meanings *in context*. For example, "Is there room in the room?"

Comment: @JeremyMiller Or my order at Starbucks, *give me a tall blonde in a venti cup*. To OP's point, such a thing could sound really rude. To your point, *context* is key!

Comment: You have made a specific point of asking how to request *your female employees* come to your office for a meeting. Please explain how their gender might make a difference to the answer you are seeking. For instance, is it a question of wishing to be politer to them than to your male employees, or of not wishing to appear to have a sexual motive for the meeting, or something else?

Comment: @ErikKowal ofcourse the main intent is to NOT to appear to have a sexual motive for the meeting..

Comment: @JeremyMiller Thank you , I appreciate your help, English language during Communication sucks sometime

Comment: In that case, the obvious answer is to include an explicit reason for your summons to the meeting. As others here have already commented, providing the women with this information will also enable them to be better prepared for the meeting. Though it may not be **required** for you "to give [a] reason each and every time to discuss ABC and discuss XYZ", surely the imperatives of normal politeness, consideration for your employees and workplace efficiency all strongly suggest that you *should* in fact explain the reason for the meeting beforehand? Not doing so suggests laziness and/or arrogance

Comment: if you have the same office as the other employees (i.e. no separate space), you can ask to come to your *desk* maybe.

Comment: Regarding "Messenger": is it Yahoo Messenger or Windows Live Messenger?

Answer (score 69):

The first problem, at least to a native English speaker, is your use of the phrase *my room* instead of *my office.* Native English speakers use *my room* most often to mean *my bedroom* or *my hotel room.* Your use of *room* to mean the room in which you work will sound strange to any native English speaker, male or female.

As others have also pointed out in comments attached to your question, we use *office* to refer to a room that people work in:

> [Definition of office in English: NOUN](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/office?searchDictCode=all)
>
> 1A **room,** set of rooms, or building used as a place of business for
> non-manual work [emphasis mine]

If we simply say *my office,* we almost always mean the room (or rooms) in which we work and have our desk. The readers of your messages will know you are not talking about the building.

There is likely a second problem. The form of your message will produce a different feeling, depending on cultural backgrounds.

For most US Americans, particularly, it is considered more polite and respectful to make a request instead of issuing an imperative (command), whether you include *please* or not. This is generally more true in cultures which more highly value the ideal of social equality among people. Of course, the average American knows that some people are in positions of greater power or a higher station than other people, but we consider it polite to at least behave as if this is not the case!

Also, you may prefer to use only two or three words, but (again in mainstream US office culture) politeness requires a few more in most situations of this kind, whether you like it or not. Many people will lose some respect for you, or think you are not socially intelligent, if you do not understand how to adapt to the situation.

We most often use questions instead of commands in this case, no matter what kind of rank relationship exists between two people. It is understood that the response will not normally be *no.*

If the person can assume your location, you do not need to say where you are.

> Hi Mary, can [or could] you come [and] see me please?
>
> Sandra, do you have a minute to come [and] speak to me?
>
> Can/could you come to my office please?

Comment: +1 for the meaning of "my room." That would definitely not be appropriate, especially when talking to someone of the opposite gender. The correct phrase is "my office."

Comment: @reirab Thanks. Actually, I will edit to include, as has been already pointed out in comments on the question, that office means room, not building, in this context.

Comment: "My room" was apparently used in the past in England to mean "my personal office" (I noticed this reading John LeCarre). But in the US, "Come to my room" means something quite different.

Comment: @JamesKing: Many of the usages in le Carré's novels are intelligence-service jargon, rather than then-ordinary British usage. I don't know what category "my room" falls into, but I wouldn't assume it's necessarily the latter.

Comment: @ruakh As someone who is British once explained to me "my room" to mean "my office" is a Victorian concept. It's probably not been used in that way in common speech since World War I. Exceptions until well in the 60's/70's: In very old-fashioned/traditional academic circles (e.g. "the professors rooms" meaning his office, not the place where he lives) and in high-level British government or civil service circles (e.g. "the ministers rooms" is sometimes still used even today). Le Carré's usage may derive from the government/civil service usage.

Answer (score 4):

If you want something informal you might say,

> Please stop by and see me.

If it's more formal you might say,

> Please come to the meeting in my office at 2.

or

> I need you to attend a meeting at 2 in my office.

or (assuming you use something like Microsoft Outlook) schedule a meeting and set the location to your office. The gender of the person involved should not matter for scheduling a meeting with a subordinate.

Comment: As it stands, "There is a meeting in my office at 2" is inadequate as an order: it is not an instruction, merely an item of information.

Comment: @ErikKowal Thanks for the feedback, I've edited it.

Comment: I've never been comfortable about "Please stop by and see me." See you about what? About how to go about firing Elliot? Or are you laying me off? Or am I getting a pay raise or a promotion? Who knows, but without a subject line the meeting almost certainly isn't going to be ordinary. I know the code words, and about the lack thereof. The lack thereof inevitably means something best left unwritten in a traceable medium such as email. Even a terse "Please stop by and see me about some work I'd like you to do for me" is better than an unadorned "Please stop by and see me" (if that's the intent).

Answer (score 3):

You can also specifically reference your desk, even if it in an office.

Could you please swing by my desk? - something quick to discuss

Let's have a meeting in my office about xyz - something that might take longer to discuss

Answer (score 2):

What about "Can you please come to my desk?"

Comment: I think this would also be polite and very clear in most situations.

Comment: Often, a business professional or superior will use the phrase "please come see me at my desk" or "will you please come see me at my desk".

Comment: This can only be used if the person does not have an office. Otherwise, it just...isn't

Comment: @Evorlor Sure it can.  Have you ever seen a superior's office that *doesn't* contain a desk?

Comment: @bcrist im not talking logistics. I'm talking about commonly used english

Comment: @Evorlor You didn't say "This usually would only be used...", you said "This can only be used..."

Comment: @bcrist right. I meant what I said. Saying come to my desk is not correct if u also have an office. Come to my desk implies that you only have a desk and not an office. Maybe it's different in different pets of the country, but that's how it is where I'm at

Answer (score 0):

For being rude:
Please come to my office.
Can you come to my office?

For being kinda OK:
Could you come to my office please?

For being polite and respectful:
I was wondering if you could come to my office please?

For being utmost polite and respectful:
I was wondering if you would be willing to come to my office please?

In traditional industry, you wanna avoid being utmost polite to build your social status, but in information industry or latest and newer industry, cooperation and getting work done together and acknowledging each other is the norm. So you can be very polite and respectful and people will consider you very professional as well.

Answer (score 0):

I notice myself using more words the less familiar I am to the other person, to enhance politeness.  Typically, choose one or more of the following:

- turn an order into a request (it's still an order, for all that it doesn't read like one, but if you expect the other person to weasel out of don g something it's perhaps worth avoiding that step)
- use the conditional (could or would, versus can)
- add stock politeness phrases.

Some examples, from brusque to very polite:

- Come to my office.
- Please come to my office.
- Can you please come to my office?
- Could you come to my office?
- Could you please come to my office? (This one is a good place to start)
- If it's not too much trouble / If you have a moment, could you please come to my office? (Works if you are English ;)

You can also make yourself sound more in need, because (obviously) anyone civilized would want to help you out:

- I really need your help / need you for a moment, if you could come to my office...

Not an exhaustive list, but hopefully enough to inspire you.

This escalation of politeness is actually a problem when I'm talking to ESL speakers; I naturally want to add filler to improve politeness when people aren't understanding what I say, and of course it's completely counterproductive...